# Casting JObject to dynamic and extracting a single property to string

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to extract a single property from a JSON object and I  do the following:

```
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(message);
        string propValue = data.propValue;
```

This works perfectly. However I want to  do it  in the same line with casting.

`string propValue = (dynamic)JObject.Parse(message).propValue;` but it returns an error that JObject doesn't contain that property. Why isn't casting working here?

Comment: You need more parentheses: `((dynamic)JObject.Parse(message)).propValue;`

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep, that was it.